# XHR POST Cannot send credentials and header

Tags: javascript, rest, web, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm getting a strange issue that I'm hoping has an extremely simple solution. I'm trying to send a POST request to a server. I have tried this using fetch and using XMLHttpRequest with no luck. My xhr request looks like the following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", location);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

My fetch request looks like the following:

```
fetch(location, {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({obj}),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok){
        response = response.json();
      } else {
        response = {};
      }
      window.console.debug(response);
    })
    .then((json) =>{
      window.console.debug(json);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      window.console.debug(error);
    });
```

Both of these have the same outcome. If I leave it like above, the credentials don't get sent so it sends an OPTIONS request and I get a 401. My Chrome Network tab Request Headers for the message looks like this:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.146.101:8005
Origin:http://localhost:8555
Referer:http://localhost:8555/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
```

If I remove the header lines, the content-type is the wrong type (obviously) and so I get a 415. The chrome network tab Request Headers message looks like this:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:504
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host:192.168.146.101:8005
Origin:http://localhost:8555
Referer:http://localhost:8555/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
```

For some reason, when I add a header, it strips the credentials. I've tried sending the encoded user:pass in the header as well like this (but obviously with the real username/password):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", location);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa('user:pass');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

This is happening in all browsers.
Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: I guess my question is really this: How can I change the content-type without it showing up under Access-Control-Request-Headers and instead just show up where the Content-Type shows up by default? The Postman plugin is able to somehow get it to show up that way, and that seems to be the only solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The withCredentials attibute only indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

did you try this ?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", location);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(user+':'+pass);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: In my original post I said that I did try what you stated and it doesn't work. The withCredentials should actually pull your cookies I believe.

Comment: Also, if what you're saying is correct, then the credentials wouldn't work WITHOUT the content-type, but they do.

Comment: you said using both withCredentials and Authorization header, the code seems fine here https://jsfiddle.net/y0wwbw6k/

Comment: If you notice, when you pass it in through setRequestHeader, it gets passed in differently. It goes under Access-Request-Control-Headers. This fails the authentication because it's not just under Authorization, which is where is goes if you just use withCredentials and don't use setRequestHeader at all. Of course, I need setRequestHeader (or another way to set content-type) to change the content-type, which is where my entire issue began, since it removes the Authorization tag.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to set the `Authorization` header yourself. You can do this in the `.open()` method: `xhr.open('POST', location, true, user, pass)`

Comment: So I went browsing through Postman's code (since the request works as desired in that) and they are doing exactly as idbehold suggested (which I've already tried) and the structure of the request looks correct. For some reason when I make the request from my code (with the same exact order and function calls), it seems to inject a lot of extra stuff (maybe from chrome since the extensions are immune from this?) and refuses to replace header items and instead adds the Access-Control-Request-Headers object and puts them there. I don't get why there's a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've discovered the issue. The issue is actually that the server responding to the REST APIs is setup to authenticate everything that comes through, including OPTIONS requests. The OPTIONS request is only created if we're trying to do this cross-origin, which I was. The browsers seem to strip authentication from OPTIONS requests, and since the server I'm trying to hit authenticates OPTIONS requests (for some unknown reason), it fails. So I've now tried just WAR'ing up my code and hosting it on the same server and I'm able to get past the authentication issues.

Comment: This was a really tough issue for me to catch. Thank for the reply!